# How to apply a CSS style to a specific row in an HTML table?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an HTML page that looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
       tbody, th, td {padding:0px;margin:0px;border:0px;}
       tr.foo { border: 1px solid blue; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr><td>Nothing
        <tr class="foo"><td>Bordered
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: the style to tbody, th and td MUST NOT be changed, since (in my real use case), these styles are applied to other pages.

What CSS pattern selector can I use to highlight (create border around) the row with class foo ?

Comment: After the corrections to the snippet, this is still showing without a border.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** I see you fixed your `border` rule. Since that comma was a question typo, the browser should interpret your CSS correctly (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/UNw7N)). Try fixing your `style` tag per Oded's comment anyway.

Your selector is correct, but your declaration <del>is</del> was wrong, there shouldn't be a comma between `solid` and `blue`:

```
tr.foo { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

And you should probably close your `td` and `tr` tags, not that it's invalid to leave them open but it's a good practice nevertheless.

Comment: And the `style` tag is missing the `type` attribute name.

Comment: @BoltClock: thanks for spotting the typo. However, after correcting the typo, the row is still not being highlighted.

Comment: @oompahloompah: What browser are you testing on?

Comment: @BoltClock: FF 3.6.14 on Ubuntu Linux. When I use Firebug and select the eleemnt, I can see that the style is correctly applied - but somehow, it is not being rendered - i.e. the border does not show. I will download another browser and test the page to see if this is a FF headf**k

Comment: @BoltClock: well what do you know, it turns out that the other guy was right. I had to use "tr.foo td" as the selector before it shows on FF. Just checked and this seems to be the case with Opera as well (I need to specify the selector down to the td)